# pandas loc by dates on intraday data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date, series

I have an intraday dataframe (index is DatetimeIndex). And days I want to loc in intraday df (it's also DatetimeIndex, thus it's representation like a date, but it's YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss and hh:mm:ss = 00:00:00).

For example:

```
intraday_df =

                       Column
Date
2005-01-03 09:30:00    0.9962
2005-01-03 09:31:00    0.9963
2005-01-03 09:32:00    0.9939
2005-01-03 09:33:00    0.9937
2005-01-03 09:34:00    0.9905
...                       ...
2021-09-16 15:56:00  148.7800
2021-09-16 15:57:00  148.7250
2021-09-16 15:58:00  148.7400
2021-09-16 15:59:00  148.8500
2021-09-16 16:00:00  148.7900

days = DatetimeIndex(['2005-03-09', '2005-03-24', '2005-03-31', '2005-04-14',
               '2005-04-18', '2005-04-22', '2005-05-24', '2005-05-25',
               '2005-06-06', '2005-06-10',
               ...
               '2020-09-10', '2020-09-15', '2020-09-18', '2020-09-28',
               '2020-10-12', '2020-10-14', '2020-12-22', '2021-01-11',
               '2021-01-28', '2021-05-07'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', length=200, freq=None)
```

I figured out something like this

```
intraday_df[pd.Series(intraday_df.index.date, index=intraday_df.index).isin(days.index.date)]
```

But it's not so good as I can see. I would like to make something like this:

```
intraday_df[intraday_df.index.to_series().agg(date).isin(days.index.date)]
```

But I don't know how to agg (or apply) date method...

Or is there is something better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.floor.html) or [`DatetimeIndex.normalize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.normalize.html) for remove times and ouput is `datetimes`, so possible match by `days`:

```
intraday_df[intraday_df.index.floor('d').isin(days)]
```

---

```
intraday_df[intraday_df.index.normalize().isin(days)]
```

Or convert both to dates by [`DatetimeIndex.date`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.date.html):

```
intraday_df[intraday_df.index.date.isin(days.date)]
```

Comment: Man, THANKS a lot! Never knew about floor method.

But it's strange that I didnt realize I could use normalize :/ I'm dissapointed in myself...

But your last advice won't work cuz df.index.date returns ndarray and it doesn't have isin method. That's why I wanted to aggregate date to Series values =)

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You could simplify the solution you have

```
intraday_df[intraday_df.index.floor().isin(days)]
```

Comment: Your solution is right but floor requires argument "freq" and 'd' worked! So your solution is right and it is the answer i'm looking for, but mr. jezrael answered first and suggested one more solution. But for others like me - IT IS ANSWER TOO!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one too:

`intraday_df[pd.Series(intraday_df.index.date).isin(days)]`

Comment: I did it first at all ;) After warning i got error and suggested that i need to specify index diretly - and that worked! Thanks for the answer!